# Non-Mainstream Chemistry

Tags: discussion

In the terms of service for Chemistry Exchange, one of the stipulations is to ask or post about “Non-Mainstream Chemistry”.
This seems rather vague and up to interpretation. What do they mean by this?
Thank you

Comment: I don't know about the SE bureaucrats, but to me, the term is an euphemism for "unscientific bullshit" and/or "stamp collecting". ;)

Comment: See also my related post about answers [here](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3484/101286), which includes more examples: "(…) such theories may include (but are not limited to) the chemical aspects of conspiracy theories (such as water fluoridation, chemtrails, World Trade Center controlled demolition, or Holocaust denial), pseudoscientific theories (such as homeopathy, water memory, perpetual motion, water-fuelled car, cold fusion, or alkaline diet), and other personal ideas that are not accepted by the scientific community."

Comment: Perhaps something like this? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/147541/what-would-result-if-i-diluted-c17h21no4-plus-unknown-fillers-into-a-solvent Not sure if non-mainstream or simply just written obscurely...

Answer (score 2):

The question may be closed as opinion based, but my interpretation is :

"Asking about things that are not, figurally or literally, mentioned and explained by many textbooks or educational sites".

It may aby also an "alternative chemistry" ( like alternative medicine), using unexpected,unusual or empirical approach, based rather on curiosity or experience than theoretical reasons.

And yet another explanation is in the @Karl comment. "Non mainstream" as "I do not really know, what I am doing, but let me pretend I do know".  A kind of charlatanism/quackery.

Comment: Thank you! I can see the alternative medicine one as a high contender for that